# Sign in to gmail and yahoo mail by emacs-w3m

Tags: email, emacs, gmail, yahoo

I use `Ubuntu 14.04`. When I tried to sign in to `gmail` I get This message in `w3m`:

> The number of redirections has exceeded a limit. This may have
>   happened due to the server side miss-configuration. Otherwise, try
>   increasing the limit, the value of `w3m-follow-redirection'.

And then an email received to me which said:

> Your Google Account ... was just used to  sign in.

Is it possible to sign in to `gmail` and `yahoo mail` by `emacs-w3m`?